How to configure YARP reverse proxy in .NET Core 8 with external IP and port, and handle cookies/sessions in iframe?
I have a .NET Core 8 project and I want to use the YARP library to implement a reverse proxy operation. The goal is to tunnel a URL defined in the Index with an external IP and port for the proxy, and perform the reverse proxy operation in an action named Proxy. I have written the Controller code and assembled it from various sources, but currently, the reverse proxy operation only works with my system’s IP. In the Proxy action, there are two variables that I don't know how to use: httpClientFactory and httpClient.
I will provide you with the complete code. I would appreciate your help in resolving this issue so that I can perform the reverse proxy operation with an external IP and port and display the content of the original URL within an iframe on my site. Additionally, I'm having trouble with cookies and sessions from the original URL being set on my site, where the iframe is loaded.
My Controller.cs :
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Security;
using System.Security.Authentication;
using System.Text.Json;
using Yarp.ReverseProxy.Configuration;
using Yarp.ReverseProxy.Forwarder;

namespace YarpExample2.Controllers
{
    public class HomeController : Controller
    {
        private static readonly string ProxiesFilePath = Path.Combine(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory, "Proxies.json");
        private readonly IHttpForwarder _httpForwarder;
        private readonly ForwarderHttpClientFactory _httpClientFactory;

        public HomeController(IHttpForwarder httpForwarder, ForwarderHttpClientFactory httpClientFactory)
        {
            _httpForwarder = httpForwarder;
            _httpClientFactory = httpClientFactory;
        }

        public IActionResult Index()
        {
            string url = "https://someurlfortest.com", ip = "111.111.111.111";
            int port = 22721;
            var guid = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
            var proxyUrl = $"https://localhost:7296/proxy/{guid}";

            var proxyData = new Dictionary<string, string>
            {
                { "Guid", guid },
                { "Url", url },
                { "Ip", ip },
                { "Port", port.ToString() }
            };

            SaveProxyConfig(proxyData);

            ViewBag.InternalLink = proxyUrl;
            return View();
        }

        public IActionResult Proxy(string guid)
        {
            var proxyData = LoadProxyConfig(guid);

            if (proxyData != null)
            {
                var baseUrl = proxyData["Url"];
                var externalIp = proxyData["Ip"];
                var port = int.Parse(proxyData["Port"]);

                var destinationUrl = baseUrl;

                var inMemoryConfigProvider = HttpContext.RequestServices.GetRequiredService<InMemoryConfigProvider>();

                var clusterId = $"proxyCluster-{guid}";
                var routeId = guid;

                var socketsHttpHandler = new SocketsHttpHandler
                {
                    Proxy = new WebProxy(externalIp,port),
                    UseProxy = true,
                    SslOptions = new SslClientAuthenticationOptions
                    {
                        EnabledSslProtocols = SslProtocols.Tls12 | SslProtocols.Tls13,
                        RemoteCertificateValidationCallback = (sender, certificate, chain, sslPolicyErrors) => true 
                    }
                };

                var newCluster = new ClusterConfig
                {
                    ClusterId = clusterId,
                    Destinations = new Dictionary<string, DestinationConfig>
                    {
                        {
                            "default", new DestinationConfig
                            {
                                Address = destinationUrl
                            }
                        }
                    },
                    HttpClient = new HttpClientConfig
                    {
                        DangerousAcceptAnyServerCertificate = true,
                        MaxConnectionsPerServer = 10
                    }
                };

                var httpClientFactory = HttpContext.RequestServices.GetRequiredService<IHttpClientFactory>();
                var httpClient = new HttpClient(socketsHttpHandler);

                var newRoute = new RouteConfig
                {
                    RouteId = routeId,
                    ClusterId = clusterId,
                    Match = new RouteMatch
                    {
                        Path = $"/proxy/{guid}"
                    }
                };

                var existingConfig = inMemoryConfigProvider.GetConfig();

                var routes = existingConfig.Routes.ToList();
                var clusters = existingConfig.Clusters.ToList();

                routes.Add(newRoute);
                clusters.Add(newCluster);

                inMemoryConfigProvider.Update(routes, clusters);

                return new EmptyResult();
            }

            return NotFound();
        }

        private void SaveProxyConfig(Dictionary<string, string> proxyData)
        {
            var proxies = new List<Dictionary<string, string>>();

            if (System.IO.File.Exists(ProxiesFilePath))
            {
                var json = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(ProxiesFilePath);
                proxies = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<List<Dictionary<string, string>>>(json);
            }

            proxies.Add(proxyData);

            var serializedProxies = JsonSerializer.Serialize(proxies);
            System.IO.File.WriteAllText(ProxiesFilePath, serializedProxies);
        }
        private Dictionary<string, string> LoadProxyConfig(string guid)
        {
            if (System.IO.File.Exists(ProxiesFilePath))
            {
                var json = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(ProxiesFilePath);
                var proxies = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<List<Dictionary<string, string>>>(json);

                return proxies?.FirstOrDefault(p => p["Guid"] == guid);
            }

            return null;
        }
    }
}

My Program.cs :
using System.Net;
using Yarp.ReverseProxy.Configuration;
using Yarp.ReverseProxy.Forwarder;

var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

builder.Services.AddControllersWithViews();

builder.Services.AddHttpClient();

builder.Services.AddSingleton<ForwarderHttpClientFactory>();

ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12 | SecurityProtocolType.Tls13;

builder.Services.AddReverseProxy()
    .LoadFromMemory(new List<RouteConfig>(), new List<ClusterConfig>());

var app = builder.Build();

if (!app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
}
app.UseHsts();

app.UseHttpsRedirection();
app.UseStaticFiles();

app.UseRouting();

app.UseAuthorization();

app.MapControllerRoute(
    name: "default",
    pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");

app.MapControllerRoute(
    name: "proxy",
    pattern: "proxy/{guid}",
    defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Proxy" });

app.MapReverseProxy();

app.Run();

